# Don't move messages if a user is kicked in the destination room

Tags: feature-request, chat

If a user is kicked from a chat room, one of their messages can still be moved from another room to the room in which they are kicked. Example: [this message of my chat bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18416646#18416646) could be moved from the Sandbox while the bot was kicked in Charcoal HQ, for testing purposes. This should probably not be allowed to prevent abuse.

Can it please be disallowed to move messages if a user is kicked from the destination room?

Comment: I believe mods need the ability to move messages to other rooms users are not typically allowed in... but I understand your concern

Answer (score 5):

Moving messages is a privilege for room owners and mods. They are expected to exercise good judgment and not misuse that feature.

If a room owner or moderator misuses this ability, they should simply be told to stop that behaviour. Removing their ability to move messages is possible, if they do not stop misusung it.

In short, I don't see a practical way to abuse this that can't be solved easier by removing room owner status or diamond from that user.

Comment: Though, can users move their own messages (i.e. I create a room for myself, then move a message from this room to any other)?

Comment: @hichris123 Room creation requires 100 rep, so this can't be easily abused with socks. Anyone that still misuses this can be simply suspended.